# Something wrong with my AngularJs code

Tags: html, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am new in Angularjs, below is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ng-Messages Service</title>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
        <script src="ng-messages.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div ng-controller='thecontroller'>
            <form name="myForm">
            <label>
              Enter text:
              <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" required minlength="5" />
            </label>
            <div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error" role="alert">
              <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
              <div ng-message="minlength, maxlength">
                Your email must be between 5 and 100 characters long
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And Below is angularjs code,

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ngMessages']);

myApp.controller('thecontroller',function($scope){
    $scope.name="Gopal";
});
```

We didn't get proper output, what's wrong with my above code.

Thanks

Comment: what output you expected?

Comment: What is `proper output`? Do you get errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: Make sure your question has all the information needed for the people here to help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
Or your question will be closed in no-time.

Comment: Why you want to give min-length and max-length validation to email rather than email should match an email pattern. It doesn't make sense you are asking i think wrong.

Comment: Oh!, I forgot to mention ng-app='myApp', I got output now.

Comment: Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not mentioned `ng-app="myApp"` in your html template.

Also make sure you have reference the .js file needed. I assume this includes the module declaration.

```
<script src="ng-messages.js"></script>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ngMessages']);

myApp.controller('thecontroller',function($scope){
    $scope.name="Gopal";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ng-Messages Service</title>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller='thecontroller'>
            <form name="myForm">
            <label>
              Enter text:
              <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" required minlength="5" />
            </label>
            <div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$error" role="alert">
              <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
              <div ng-message="minlength, maxlength">
                Your email must be between 5 and 100 characters long
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh!, I forgot to mention ng-app='myApp', I got output now.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to specify ng-app="your Module name" to bootstrap the application when index.html page start to load. It triggers the AngularJs life cycle automatically.
 Note- You may also specify the pattern for validating email that is email is valid or not
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html >
            <head>
                <title>ng-Messages Service</title>
                <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
                <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js'></script>
                <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
                <script src="ng-messages.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body ng-app="myApp">

                <div ng-controller='thecontroller'>
                    <form name="myForm">
                    <label>
                      Enter text:
                      <input type="text" placeholder="abc@eyz.com" ng-model="field" name="myField"  data-ng-required="true" minlength="5" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/i"/>
                    </label>
                      <div data-ng-show="myForm.myField.$error.required">You did not enter a field</div>
                      <div data-ng-show="myForm.myField.$error.min 
                                                                || myForm.myField.$error.max">
                        Your email must be between 5 and 100 characters long
                      </div>
                      <div data-ng-show="myForm.myField.$error.pattern" >The email id is not valid</div
                    </form>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```